# About the information in the thanks note put in two column IEEE jounal

Tags: overleaf, ieeetran, author, ieee-style, ieeetrantools

I'm trying to submit a paper to IEEE journals, and has some much information to put at the thanks note at the first page.
However, I found that if I put the thanks note of the institues that support us togehter with the author (there are four) informations, that would be a huge footnote block at the left column in page 1.
Therefore, is there any adjustments by IEEE format to the put part of thanks note (in my case, the author information) to the right column in page 1?

It is ideal if thanks notes to be in the footnote at left column and author information to be in the footnote at the right column.
The following picture is a word template that IEEE provide but not included in the example of latex files. The red box is what the effect that I want to achieve.

[image]

Below is the MWE that contains the information that I want to put in our paper (of course, all names has changed to be anonymous). As you can see if you put in the overleaf website, it is a large box of foot note at the bottom left.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Paper title}

\author{AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, \IEEEmembership{Junior Member, IEEE}%
\thanks{Manuscript received September X, 20X. This research was supported in part by the Ministry of Magical (MM) of the Empire of the Earth (Taiwan) under Grant Number ABC-DEFG-H-IJK-123
, ABC-DEFG-H-IJK-231, and ABC-DEFG-H-IJK-321 through Language of Spells Research (LSR) Labs, and the computing resource was supported in part by Desert for High-Protein Provider (DHPP) of Tailan. (Corresponding author: DDD.)}

\thanks{AAA is with the Department of Food Recycling, Jump High Laugh High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: aaa@foodre.jhlh.ee).}
\thanks{BBB is with the Department of Food Exploring, Jump High Laugh High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: bbb@foodex.jhlh.ee).}
\thanks{CCC is with the Department of Food Recycling, Jump High Laugh High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: ccc@foodre.jhlh.ee).}
\thanks{DDD is with the Department of Bungee Jumping, Jump High Smile High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: ddd@bj.jhsh.ee).}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load [ftnright](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ftnright) package and you will get all footnotes at the end of the right column on each page. Note, the author recommends to load this package as the last.

Comment: Thanks for your information, @Celdor. But I don't want all the information to be put at the bottom of the right column. I have posted a new picture whihch has the effect that I desired.

Comment: The document shown indicates that it is possible, but the IEEEtran manual doesn't say how.  There is a newer IEEE template, but last time I checked there was no manual (online help only).

Comment: Visit https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/

Comment: @JohnKormylo The newest version of IEEE latex template provides two .tex files. These two files only show thanks note in the left page. The picture that I posted is the newest version of IEEE word template which has the desired effect that I want.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

One could pre-format the `\thanks` into left and right blocks using saveboxes and `\vsplit`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% seriously?
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{afterpage}

\title{Paper title}

\author{AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, \IEEEmembership{Junior Member, IEEE}%
\thanks{Manuscript received September X, 20X. This research was supported in part by the Ministry of Magical (MM) of the Empire of the Earth (Taiwan) under Grant Number ABC-DEFG-H-IJK-123
, ABC-DEFG-H-IJK-231, and ABC-DEFG-H-IJK-321 through Language of Spells Research (LSR) Labs, and the computing resource was supported in part by Desert for High-Protein Provider (DHPP) of Tailan. (Corresponding author: DDD.)}
\thanks{\rule{0pt}{2\baselineskip}}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\afterpage{\let\thanks=\footnotetext
\let\thefootnote=\relax
\thanks{AAA is with the Department of Food Recycling, Jump High Laugh High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: aaa@foodre.jhlh.ee).}
\thanks{BBB is with the Department of Food Exploring, Jump High Laugh High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: bbb@foodex.jhlh.ee).}
\thanks{CCC is with the Department of Food Recycling, Jump High Laugh High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: ccc@foodre.jhlh.ee).}
\thanks{DDD is with the Department of Bungee Jumping, Jump High Smile High University, ABC, the Empire of the Earth (e-mail: ddd@bj.jhsh.ee).}
}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```